# Custom Button next to “ADD TO CART” button of WooCommerce based on Product Type

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want add a custom Button "View Demo" next to "Add to Cart" button of WooCommerce based on Product Type, both on main shop page and single product page.

I've done this steps:

Add code to theme file `header.php`:

```
<script>var url_demo = "<?php echo the_field('url_demo'); ?>"</script>
```

Add jQuery script using "TC Custom JavaScript" plugin:

```
jQuery(function($) {
 $('.add_to_cart_button, .single_add_to_cart_button').after(' <a class="button demo_button" style="padding-right: 0.75em;padding-left: 0.75em;margin-left: 8px; background-color: #0ebc30;" href="'+url_demo+'" target="_blank">View Demo</a>');
});
```

It's work, the Custom button "View Demo" shown on main shop page and single product page.

But I've some problem now, the "View Demo" button link only correct on Single Product page, while on shop main page the "View Demo" button, link to the same url. Is my code above wrong?

My questions are, how to add "View Demo" button (both on main shop page and single product page) that only show for spesific product type, for example only show on category **Theme**? Last, is there any other way to add demo link without editing the `header.php` file like above method? I just anticipating the `header.php` file reset if the theme updated.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your web site please?

Comment: Sure, here is the [link](http://akunikah.com/shop/)

Comment: I'm sorry for displaying your answer on my question last time. I've removed it. I've implement your last _UPDATED 2_ answer, and my web going down and can't be accessed, I don't know why. Then, I reset the functions.php to default and the web going online again. And now, I just implement your _UPDATE_ using `get_field()`, it's work great. Everything going good just like what I want. Thanks for your answer, my problem solved.

Comment: OK. You can do it.

Comment: Oh, I used the demo link on product description because I have not find method to add button next to add to cart. And since this can be done now, I'll remove the demo button on product description. Thanks for remember me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am using another way to do it: **WooCommerce hooks**.

**You don't need anymore** the jQuery script and also the javascript located in your **header.php** file, so you can erase them.

Using `get_field()` instead of `the_field` (thanks to [Deepti chipdey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5575345/deepti-chipdey)) to get only the value concatenated in the `echoed` string.

Paste this code snippet in your **function.php** file located in your active child theme or theme folder:

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
    echo '<a class="button demo_button" style="padding-right: 0.75em;padding-left: 0.75em;margin-left: 8px; background-color: #0ebc30;" href="'.get_field( "url_demo" ).'" target="_blank">View Demo</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20 );
```

I have target the hooks used to display **Add to cart** button on shop page and in single product pages, to display your **View demo** button after it, buy lowering the priority.

Comment: I've done this step. But it seems weird, the links of the buttons are place outside the button, look at this [SS](http://prntscr.com/b46nj8), and this on [single product page](http://prntscr.com/b46o8o). And the button still shown on not "Theme" product category. Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37229440/8255629) did not do it for me.

Here is what worked:

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
    echo '<a class="button demo_button" href="'.get_field( "url_demo" ).'" target="_blank">View Demo</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_demo_button' );
```

Hope that helps someone in their journey.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
the_field('url_demo');
```

to

```
 get_field('url_demo');
```

Comment: it's AFC code the_field echo the code by default but get_filed will give you value in variable

Comment: it's AFC code the_field echo the field value by default but get_filed will give you value in the variable

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the above answers throw an error for me. I use these codes and combined them with other codes and came to a solution.

1. Edit the Woocommerce product and add an attribute to it with the name of `url_demo` and the value of `your-demo-url`.
2. Add the below code to your child theme **functions.php** file (or your parent theme but I don't recommend it):

```
/* Adding demo button to Woocommmerce products */
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
  $product = wc_get_product(get_the_id());
  $url_demo = $product->get_attribute('url_demo');
  echo '<a class="button" href="'.$url_demo.'" target="_blank">View Demo</a>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20);
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20);
```