# How to add "show details" button near the cart button in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, addition, woocommerce-theming

I want to add additional button in woocommerce single product. In which file I need to make changes?

Example on screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0KZE.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Button next to “ADD TO CART” button of WooCommerce based on Product Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228791/custom-button-next-to-add-to-cart-button-of-woocommerce-based-on-product-type)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228791/custom-button-next-to-add-to-cart-button-of-woocommerce-based-on-product-type

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
function wc_shop_demo_button() {
    echo '<a class="button demo_button" style="padding-right: 0.75em;padding-left: 0.75em;margin-left: 8px; background-color: #0ebc30;" href="'.get_field( "url_demo" ).'" target="_blank">Show Details</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_shop_demo_button', 20 );
```

Hope this will helps you. For more details visit,

[how to add button after woocommerce shop loop item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228791/custom-button-next-to-add-to-cart-button-of-woocommerce-based-on-product-type)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a Custom Field using Advanced Custom Fields plugin for Woocommerce Product Page.

For creating a custom field using the ACF plugin, refer to the below article.

https://wpmayor.com/woocommerce-custom-fields-how-to-create-and-display-them/

To display the Custom Button in the frontend of the website, add the below code in functions.php file.

```
function rf_custom_product_button() {
    echo '<a class="button custom_button" href="'.get_field( "custom_button" ).'" target="_blank">Click Here</a>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'rf_custom_product_button', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'rf_custom_product_button', 20 );
```

In the above code, Change the "custom_button" to the name of the field which you create using ACF.